# Unordered Array Linear Search c++

Tags: c++, arrays

My assignment is to : Create a method to search an un-ordered array of integers for a value, 
if the value is found return the index of its position in the array, if not found, return -1.

It is only finding the number I enter if it is in Index 0, otherwise it is saying it is not found. I am not sure what went wrong, it was working when I had initialized my own array, but now it won't since I have the user create their own array.

Any help would be great! thanks!

So far my code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


//SearchArray prototype
int SearchArray( int arInt[], int elementAmount, int intSearched);


int main()

{
    int arInt[50];
    int elementAmount;
    int intSearched = 0;
    int i;

    cout << "How many elements would you like to add to your array?\n";
    cin >> elementAmount;

    for( i = 0; i < elementAmount; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Number: ";
        cin >> arInt[i];
    }

        cout << "Search array for integer:\n";
        cin >> intSearched;

        //Call search array method
        SearchArray(arInt, elementAmount, intSearched);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int SearchArray( int arInt[], int elementAmount, int intSearched)
{
        int i;
        bool foundInt = false;

        for (i=0; i < elementAmount; i++)
        {
            if( arInt[i] == intSearched)
            {
                foundInt = true;
                cout << "Integer was found in array at index " << i << endl;
            }
            else if (!foundInt)
            {
                cout << "Integer was not found in array\n";

                system("pause");
                return -1;
            }


        }

}
```

Comment: Why isn't there any code in `SearchArray` method?

Comment: What happens when you run this under the debugger?

Comment: Apart from everything else, this code has very dangerous error - SearchArray doesn't return value when the element was found in the array.

Comment: That else-if has no business being *inside* the for-loop. Move it after and lose the `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following code to the `SearchArray` method in your code, and it works fine

```
int SearchArray( int arInt[], int elementAmount, int intSearched)
{
    for(int i=0; i< elementAmount; i++)
    {
        if (arInt[i] == intSearched)
            return i;
    }
    // element not found!
    return -1;
}
```

And add the following at the end of your `main` to retrieve the ans

```
int ans = SearchArray(arInt, elementAmount, intSearched);
cout<<"Indexed of the element"<<ans<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you always end your search on first element. Suppose array is

```
arr=[3,5,7] and intSearched is 5.
```

Now in your `SearchArray()` function `foundInt` is initially set to false. So when `i = 0 and arInt[i] == intSearched` condition is not true, it goes to `else` statement since `foundInt` is `false`. And from there you return `-1`. Something like below would be simpler and do the job:

```
int SearchArray(int *arInt, int elementAmount, int intSearched)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < elementAmount; i++)
    {
        if(arInt[i] == intSearched)
        {
            cout << "Integer was found in array at index " << i << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "Integer was not found in array\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```